Why 'unsigned int' are sign-extended to 64bit register value in riscv64 Integer Calling Convention?
The Integer Calling Convention of riscv is described as below:

Scalars that are at most XLEN bits wide are passed in a single
argument register, or on the stack by value if none is available. When
passed in registers or on the stack, integer scalars narrower than
XLEN bits are widened according to the sign of their type up to 32
bits, then sign-extended to XLEN bits.

The result is, a parameter of 'unsigned short' type will be zero-extended to 64bit, while a parameter of 'unsigned int' type will be sign-extended to 64bit. So why not all zero-extended? (Since both are of unsigned type, and 'unsigned int' is always zero-extended in C Implicit type conversion rules.)
For example,
void foo(unsigned short x)
void bar(unsigned int x);

void main(void)
{
    foo(0xffffU);
    bar(0xffffffffU);
}

Generated code:
main:
        ...
        li      a5,65536
        addi    a0,a5,-1
        call    foo
        li      a0,-1
        call    bar



Uniformity: By always sign-extending, the calling convention ensures that the upper bits of all narrower-than-XLEN integer arguments are consistent (copies of the sign bit).

Consistency of operation

Simpler Code Generation: Compilers can generate more efficient code when they can assume that all integer arguments are sign-extended to 64 bits


There is no loss of information and upper bits are ignored.
For 32-bit extensions, it is not possible for obvious reasons - ie to preserve the correct values.
